# PHP HTTP Request

Tags: php

Хочу наладить общение одного php файла с другим. 
Код первого:

```
<?php 
$url = 'ссылка'; 
if ($http = new HttpRequest($url, HttpRequest::METH_POST)){ 
echo "robit"; 
} else { 
echo "ne robit"; 
} 
$http->setOptions(array('cookies' => array('lang' => 'de'))); 
$http->addPostFields(array( 
'firstData' => 'myData', 
'secondData' => 'myDataTwo' 
)); 
try{ 
$response = $http->send(); 
echo $response->getBody(); 
} catch (HttpException $ex) { 
echo $ex; 
} 
?>
```

Код другого файла:

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
?>
```

Первый проверки проходит, якобы отправляет. А второй вовсе не видит. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так.

Comment: я может не шарю, но вроде он там есть. в строчке: $response = $http->send(); 
где, в хттп я кладу массив. Или я не права?

Comment: это я прозевал:)

Comment: а в самом `$response ` что-нибудь есть? `print_r` что покажет? может быть `$response->getResponseCode()` посмотреть?

Comment: Я не особо понимаю, поэтому просто покажу вывод http://uploads.ru/FNrxW.png для print_r
Во втором случае, примерно то же самое выводит.

Comment: У вас есть ответ! Уточните, что не работает?

Comment: Если написать не `getBody()`, а `getResponseBody()` что-нибудь отобразится? вместо `echo ` надо бы `print_r` или `var_dump`...... .....и у меня что-то сомнения на счет `var_dump($_POST);` во втором файле...

Comment: Говорит, что не может найти такой метод как getResponseBody()

Comment: Я еще решила сменить url на ложный, и тогда при выводе ничего не отображается. также, переменная не пуста. Думаю, что проблема со вторым файлом. Только я не знаю как ее решить.

Comment: Попробуйте во 2 файле написать просто `echo 'Hello, world!'`. в первом файле выводить информацию все же через `print_r` в любом случае... что произойдет?

Comment: Изменила первый файл на print_r, страница не может выполнить запрос теперь. Вторая отобразила "привет мир"

Comment: вместо `echo $response->getBody();` написали `print_r($response->getBody());` и не выполняется запрос? если в начало файла написать `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);` ошибки будут какие-либо?

Comment: Простите, это я накосячила. Поэтому запрос не выполнялся. Теперь он выводит robit(вывод из первого условия) и Hello world (видимо берет из второго скрипта). Так должно быть?

Comment: Ну да... мы же во втором скрипте отдаем этот контент...........а вообще, в своем коде какой результат вы планировали видеть?  Ведь, как сказал @borodatych - у вас итак выводился ответ))) Т.е. все работало))) Что вы ожидали чтоб было?

Comment: :D Я тупица. Я думала, что информацию, которую я передам, выводится во втором файле. Что в принципе мне и нужно было. Думала, что http request поможет мне с реализацией. Спасибо вам большое за терпение и помощь!

Comment: хых,ну бывает))

Comment: Все верно мыслите - информацию, что передали вы можете обработать во втором файле, а вернуть не то что пришло, а ответ об успехе той или иной операции.

Comment: да, спасибо вам большое) я все смогла сделать, все получилось как я хотела. спасибо, что разжевали!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте вывод ошибки:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$url = '/path/to/script2.php';
if ($http = new HttpRequest($url, HttpRequest::METH_POST)){
    echo "robit";
} else {
    echo "ne robit";
}
$http->setOptions(array('cookies' => array('lang' => 'de')));
$http->addPostFields(array(
    'firstData' => 'myData',
    'secondData' => 'myDataTwo'
));
try{
    $response = $http->send();
    echo $response->getBody();
} catch (HttpException $ex) {
    echo $ex;
}
```

Если нет нужного расширения, как у меня, то при запуске получите:

```
Fatal error: Class 'HttpRequest' not found in /path/to/script1.php on line 7
```

Если оно так, то вам нужно установить расширение:

```
$ pecl install -f pecl_http-1.7.6
```

Но я бы бросил взор в сторону cURL!
**Script1**:

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);

$request = function($url,$body=NULL){
    $userAgent = ($ua=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ?$ua :"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36";
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,$userAgent);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "api://domain.ru");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,30); /// 5
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_DNS_CACHE_TIMEOUT, 0);
    if( $body ){
        $body = (is_array($body)) ? http_build_query($body) : $body;
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$body);
    }
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    return $result;
};
$url = '/path/to/script2.php';
$post = array(
    'firstData' => 'myData',
    'secondData' => 'myDataTwo'
);
$response = $request($url,$post);
$response =  json_decode($response);
print"<pre>\n";print_r($response);print"</pre>\n";exit;
```

**Script2**:

```
<?php die(json_encode($_POST));
```

Comment: Ошибку не дал. Вот такой вывод получился. 
http://uploads.ru/FNrxW.png
Только я там добавила print_r для респонс.

Comment: Странно, но ваш вывод (cURL)  у меня тоже не работает.

Comment: Попробуйте `код-один-в-один`, только пути свои. Так же посмотрите какая ошибка в логах красуется.

Comment: Я прям скопипастила код. Только свой путь вставила. Все равно второй файл ничего не показывает.

Comment: Если вы на прямую пытаетесь запустить `Script2`, то вы ни чего и не увидите, так как переменной `$_POST` не существует. Ответ нужно ловить в `Script1`.

Comment: Извините, но можно подробнее. Не совсем пока понимаю.

Comment: Попробуйте в `Script2 ` прописать такое `<?php die(json_encode(array('QWERTY',$_POST)));`.